# Concourse "no basic auth credentials" when trying to push with docker-image resource to AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, concourse

I need to push an image to AWS ECR with Concourse
There seem to be a bug in the latest versions, so I downgraded to Concourse 3.0.1 and used a custom resource type as recommended in this work-around: https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/1252

Still, I get a "no basic auth credentials" when trying to push to ECR
here is how I declare the resource type:

```
resource_types:
  - name: docker-image-2
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: concourse/docker-image-resource
      tag: docker-1.12.6
resources:
  - name: genesis-builder-docker-image
    type: docker-image-2
    source:
      repository: xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/genesis-builder
      aws_access_key_id: concourse-ecr
      aws_secret_access_key: xxxx
```

any idea welcome ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad, I used IAM username instead of access key id.
also, works with the stock docker-image-resource, no need to define a resource type.